# Command to download an artifact from Artifactory server to local using maven command

Tags: maven, artifactory, artifacts

I have an artifactory set up which holds number of jar files. I can only Find vedios or contents to  Upload an artifact to artfactory using maven command. But can you please help me with command on how to download an artifact to local server from artfactory using maven command

Comment: Define the artifact as a dependency in a Maven/Gradle build and it will be downloaded automatically if everything is correctly configured...

Comment: So we need to add the dependancy in settings.xml or Pom.xml

Comment: In Maven you have to add dependencies in the `pom.xml` file..you should read the documentation....